# characteristic function of a clopen set continuous?

Tags: analysis, continuity, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $C(X)$ the continuous functions complex valued on $X$ and $U\subset X$ clopen. Is then the characteristic function $1_U\in C(X)$? $1_U:X\to\mathbb{C}$ is defined by $1_U(x)=1$, if $x\in U$, and zero otherwise.

In general, this function is not continuous. But with $U$ clopen I don't know.

Comment: What is the inverse image of any set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is any subset of $\mathbb{C}$ then

- $(1_U)^{-1}[A] = U$ iff $1 \in A, 0 \notin A$,
- $(1_U)^{-1}[A] = X\setminus U$ iff $0 \in A, 1 \notin A$,
- $(1_U)^{-1}[A] = X$ iff $\{0,1\} \subseteq A$, and
- $(1_U)^{-1}[A] = \emptyset$ iff $\{0,1\} \cap A = \emptyset$

So for all (open) $A$ the inverse image is open (as $U$ is clopen).
So $1_U$ is continuous.

Comment: On the second item, I can apply $1_{U} $ from the left and get that the expression on the left implies the expression on the right. From that, I think we can get an iff relationship. I imagine the same would apply for the fourth item. Why is it that you avoided "iff" specifically in the second and fourth item? Am I mistaken?

Comment: @evaristegd you are right they’re all iff.