# Continuous Characteristic Function

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and $K$ is a compact subset of $X$. We denote the characteristic/indicator function of $K$ as $1_K$. My question is: Can we conclude the following?

$1_K$ is continuous on $X$ if and only if $K$ is open.

Intuitively, it does make sense to me that $1_K$ is continuous if and only if $K$ is both open and closed.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: $1_K^{-1}((0,\infty))=K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $K$ is open and closed, $1_K$ is continuous as I show [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3000898/4280).

OTOH, if $1_K$ is continuous $K = 1_K^{-1}[\{1\}] = 1_K^{-1}[\{(0,+\infty)\}]$ is open and closed.

So both directions hold.